# SQLServerCE cannot use rtrim in select statement - SQLCEException

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, sql-server-ce, sqlexception

I am writing a windows mobile application that uses SQL CE. It is not returning any rows when I include the `WHERE Barcode = @Barcode` statement.

I am guessing this is because the value for Barcode has trailing spaces after it. So I want to use `WHERE rtrim(Barcode) LIKE @Barcode`. But it is giving me a `SqlCeException` saying "The specified argument value for the function is not valid."

I'm sure I am missing something stupid here. Any help greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

namespace ElectricBarcodeApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection(
            ("Data Source=" + (System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase), "ElectricReading.sdf") + ";Max Database Size=2047")));
            try
            {
                // Connect to the local database
                conn.Open();
                System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

                SqlCeParameter param = new SqlCeParameter();
                param.ParameterName = "@Barcode";
                param.Value = textBarcode.Text.Trim();



                // Insert a row
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Location, Reading FROM Main2 WHERE rtrim(Barcode) LIKE @Barcode";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                DataTable data = new DataTable();

                using (SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        data.Load(reader);
                    }
                }
                if (data != null)
                {
                    this.dataGrid1.DataSource = data;
                }

            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }



        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ElectricReadingDataSetUtil.DesignerUtil.IsRunTime())
            {
                // TODO: Delete this line of code to remove the default AutoFill for 'electricReadingDataSet.Main2'.
                this.main2TableAdapter.Fill(this.electricReadingDataSet.Main2);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you can't RTRIM an NTEXT or TEXT column. This also applies to standard SQL Server.

You have to convert it to NVARCHAR first:

```
SELECT Location, Reading FROM Main2 WHERE rtrim(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, Barcode)) LIKE @Barcode
```

Answer (score 0):

SqlCE supports `rtrim`, so that shouldn't be your problem. Do you really need to do a `LIKE` here? Does the code run if you replace `LIKE` with `=`?

Comment: no because the sqlce database has it defined as ntext which doesn't work with =, I guess I'll change the data type and give it a try

Comment: changed it to = and still no change

Comment: Hmm, do you have any NULL values in your Barcode column? Possibly rtrim doesn't work with NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you replace this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Location, Reading FROM Main2 WHERE rtrim(Barcode) LIKE @Barcode";
```

with this (note I removed rtrim):

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Location, Reading FROM Main2 WHERE Barcode LIKE @Barcode";
```

and then this:

```
param.Value = textBarcode.Text.Trim();
```

with this (adding the wildcard so the LIKE can match it):

```
param.Value = textBarcode.Text.Trim() + "%";
```

Comment: I'd test the perf of this agains thte CONVERT option.  I honestly have no idea which is faster (though I'd personally go with the option of not using SQL at all but use `TableDirect` and `Seek`, which would be faster than *either* method by an order of magnitude).